# What's the difference between $(this) and this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

What's the difference between `$(this)` and `this` in jQuery, and why do they sometimes give the same result and other times behave differently?

Comment: when do they "*give the same result*" ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$(this)` wraps `this` with the jQuery functionality.

For example, this code would fail:

```
$('.someDiv').onClick(function(){
    // this refers to the DOM element so the following line would fail
    this.fadeOut(100);
});
```

So we wrap `this` in jQuery:

```
$('.someDiv').onClick(function(){
    // wrap this in jQuery so we can use jQuery fadeOut
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

`$(this)` decorates whatever object `this` points to with the jQuery functions. The typical use case is for `this` to reference a DOM element (say, a `<div>`). Then, writing `$(this)` allows you to use all the jQuery API functions on that `<div>`.

If `this` already refers to a jQuery object - usually a jQuery-decorated DOM object - then calling `$(this)` will have no effect because it's already decorated.

Answer (score 4):

If in your current context if the `this` is not a jQuery object, you can make it a jQuery element by wrapping it around `$()`. When your element already is a result of jQuery expression, the `this` in that case is already a jQuery object. So in that case they both work similarly

Answer (score 3):

for you to understand a little bit better, get yourself a debugger of somekind such as google chrome and do this..

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log(this); //DO
    console.log($(this)); //JO
});
```

this will show you what the difference is :)

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a javascript variable created whenever you are inside a function which is attached to an object. In these cases, `this` refers to that object.

`$(this)` returns a jQuery object which you can call jQuery functions on, but will apply only to `this`.

For example, if you set a click handler for all anchors:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.href) ;
}) ;
```

then the `this`, refers to the anchor, which the click event (function) is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

$(this) == this ? interesting.

this must not pass by DOM event.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function that is executing. Using $(this) will only wrap the owner so that all the jQuery operations will be extended and available to it.

Consider:

```
$links = $('#content a');

$links.click(function() {
    link  = this;
    $link = $(this); //jQuery wrapped object.

    alert(link.getAttribute('href'));        
    alert($link.attr('href')); //we can use the attr() function from jQuery
});
```

They usually give the same results since the owner is the same, only that when wrapped by jQuery it can operate with the jQuery functions.