# Anyone guide the difference of Jquery "this" and $(this)

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between $(this) and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722544/what-is-the-difference-between-this-and-this)

Anyone guide the difference of Jquery `this` and `$(this)`. Like in the below code I when I try to use `$(this).id` does not work and if I use `this.id` its working. I thought there is no difference between `$(this)` and `this`. I appreciate If someone explain the reason.

```
$(function($){
 //This work

  $('p').append( $('input').map(function(){   
     return  this.id;
  }).get().join(', '));

//This is not working? Could you explain what's the reason

  $('p').append( $('input').map(function(){   
     return  $(this).id;
  }).get().join(', '));

});
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 2):

"this" is a direct reference to the DOM node, without any interference from jQuery. It would be the same as calling document.getElementById();

Wrapping it with $() returns a jQuery object, which has a different set of properties and methods. In particular, the jQuery object does not have an id attribute - you would have to instead do

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

Both syntaxes are correct, however if you simply want to grab the id of the DOM node, "this.id" would be faster.