# jQuery this.href String Comparison Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, href

I have a simple jQuery script that I'm trying to build upon but I can't get the href string comparison to return true:

```
<a class="test" href="/Services/Cloud-Hosting">Click Me</a>​
```

My script is as follows:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
if ($(this).href == "/Services/Cloud-Hosting") {
    alert('hi');
}
else {
    alert('no');
}
});​
```

I keep getting the alert of 'no' even thought the hrefs are the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Now after you got your answer, check this to know the explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722544/what-is-the-difference-between-this-and-this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
if ($(this).href
```

To:

```
if (this.href
```

Or `$(this).attr('href')` but former is better.

To read attributes, you need to use `attr` (shorthand for `attribute`)

This is what you should have:

```
if (this.href == "/Services/Cloud-Hosting") {
    alert('hi');
}
else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Comment: Be careful using `this.href`, in Chrome it returns the absolute path of the link (regardless of the `href` being a relative URL). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCx6D/).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica that tip is so valuable, that I reckon it merits posting a new answer with that guidance so that researchers have an easier time understanding the difference.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Services/Cloud-Hosting") {
```

Answer (score 1):

See [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and try this:

```
$(this).attr('href') == "/Services/Cloud-Hosting"
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects don't have an `href` property. Just access the property of the [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement) using `this.href` instead of creating a new jQuery object with `$(this)`.

Comment: As noted to another answer `this.href` isn't necessarily equal to `$(this).attr('href')`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCx6D/).

Comment: @DavidThomas In that case wouldn't `this.getAttribute('href')` be the preferred way?