# What is the difference between this and $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between $(this) and this in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685508/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery)

In [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), the example code is:

```
<body>
  <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">

    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>

    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
<script>

    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " "; // I interested it this line
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .trigger('change');
</script>

</body>
```

In the example code, there is a portion of code:

```
str += $(this).text() + " ";
```

I am wondering, why here does not use `str += this.text() + " ";`? In another word, why not use `this` but use `$(this)` in that portion of code? what is the difference between `this` and `$(this)` in this circumstance?

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the difference between $(this) and this in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685508/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery) and/or [jQuery $(this) vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) and/or a few others :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `each` function sets `this` to the *raw* DOM element for each call to the iteration callback ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)). Calling `$()` on that raw element gives you a jQuery object wrapped around it, giving you access to the jQuery functions such as `text`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a standard javascript obect, `$(this)` is the jQuery-wrapped object, exposing all the jQuery goodness like functions and properties that regular JavaScript does not.

Sometimes the jQuery wrapper is not needed, and could be considered overkill.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason you use `$("select")` and not `select`.  It puts the object into proper jQuery context and returns the jQuery-wrapped object(s).

Answer (score 0):

$("this") is jquery and 'this' is javascript.