# General script: selecting the input element for which keypress event is fired, without actually passing the ID etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a general Jquery script for validation and I am stack at selecting the element for which the keypress event is fired, without actually passing the ID element `#elementid` specified in the below code.-->`var element = **pick the object**// $('input[type=number][validate=something]');`.

- Note that the below code pickup all the input field of number type and attribute value of `validation` as`something`.
- get the value of maxlength of the field for which keypress event has occured.
- avoid java script function call inside input.
- write a general script that could be applicable for all page and not pick element by id attribute.

Sample JS below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Validation</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <input validate="something"  type="number" maxlength="9"  />
    <input validate="something" type="number" maxlength="9"  />

<script>
$('input[type=number][validate=something]').on('keypress', function(evt,obj) {
                var element =**pick the object**// $('input[type=number][validate=SSN]');
                var len = element.val().length + 1;
                var max = element.attr("maxlength");

                if (!(len <= max)) {
                    // some code
                }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var element = $(this)`. (jQuery automatically sets the function context to the element the event is being fired on. So, again `this` is your friend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you've hooked the event on is available within the handler as `this`; to wrap it in an jQuery object, use `$()`:

```
var element = $(this);
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck finding a dupe target for this, but surely there must be...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — May be [__What's the difference between $(this) and this in jQuery?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685508/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is the dupe link .. you can duplicate it http://stackoverflow.com/q/48239/5086633  surprised by looking at the views for this question 784,472 .. my guilt feeling is gone :)

Comment: @yeppe: Yeah, I looked at that one, but I thought the meaning was obscured by the whole `id` thing, and the most upvoted answers there focus (sometimes somewhat erroneously) on `e.target`. I think I'll probably expand the community wiki answer above a bit and start referring to this question. If you don't mind, I'll probably edit the question to be a bit more focussed as well to make it more broadly-applicable.

Comment: @yeppe: I'll probably get to it today. Probably. It *is* on my list.

Comment: @yeppe: If I had a link to it, I could see it, but I can't *search* for it if you follow me. It's not shown in lists.

Comment: @yeppe: The place for that kind of question, btw, is http://meta.stackexchange.com or http://meta.stackoverflow.com.